android list binder interfaces
service list tracing output:
./strace -e ioctl service list
ioctl(3, BINDER_VERSION, 0x7fec428910)  = 0
ioctl(3, BINDER_SET_MAX_THREADS, 0x7fec428928) = 0
ioctl(3, _IOC(_IOC_WRITE, 0x62, 0x10, 0x4), 0x7fec428a48) = 0
ioctl(3, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fec428bf0) = 0
ioctl(3, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fec428a58) = 0
ioctl(3, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fec428b78) = 0
ioctl(3, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fec428b78) = 0
ioctl(3, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fec428af0) = 0
ioctl(3, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fec428bc8) = 0
Found 298 services:
ioctl(3, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fec428b20) = 0
ioctl(3, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fec428a78) = 0
ioctl(3, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fec428a78) = 0
ioctl(3, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fec428bf8) = 0
ioctl(3, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fec428b90) = 0
ioctl(3, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fec428c68) = 0
0       DockObserver: []
ioctl(3, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fec428dd8) = 0
ioctl(3, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fec428db8) = 0
ioctl(3, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fec428b20) = 0
ioctl(3, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fec428a78) = 0
ioctl(3, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fec428a78) = 0
ioctl(3, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fec428bf8) = 0
ioctl(3, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fec428b90) = 0
ioctl(3, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fec428c68) = 0
1       SurfaceFlinger: [android.ui.ISurfaceComposer]


help me complete the following code to list binder services
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct binder_write_read {
    uint64_t write_size;
    uint64_t write_buffer;
    uint64_t read_size;
    uint64_t read_buffer;
    uint64_t position;
    uint64_t flags;
};

typedef struct {
    uint32_t service_name_length;
    char service_name[256];
} binder_service_info;

int main() {
    int binder_fd;
    struct binder_write_read bwr;
    ssize_t bytes_read;

    binder_fd = open("/dev/binder", O_RDWR);
    if (binder_fd < 0) {
        perror("Failed to open /dev/binder");
        return 1;
    }
    
    bwr.write_size = 0;
    bwr.write_buffer = 0;
    bwr.read_size = 4096;
    bwr.read_buffer = (uint64_t)malloc(bwr.read_size);
    if (bwr.read_buffer == 0) {
        perror("Failed to allocate read buffer");
        close(binder_fd);
        return 1;
    }
    bwr.position = 0;
    bwr.flags = 0;
    
    if (ioctl(binder_fd, BINDER_GET_SERVICE_LIST, &bwr) < 0) {
        perror("IOCTL failed");
        free((void *)bwr.read_buffer);
        close(binder_fd);
        return 1;
    }
    
    // Process and print the service information
    

    close(binder_fd);
    return 0;
}

